# Raspberry Pi 4 - Adafruit MAX98357 - No Sound from speaker

Tags: audio, pi-4, adafruit

We are following this: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-max98357-i2s-class-d-mono-amp/overview tutorial to setup our Raspberry Pi 4 with an Adafruit MAX98357 I2S Class-D Mono Amp to a speaker (4 Ohm) as seen in the images.

The problem is we don't get any sound from the speaker. We have tried different cables to no success. Also we checked the GPIO pin activity to see if there were any errors, but everything seems to be in place correctly.

Are there more things we can try to fix this problem? Below are a few images of our setup. Thanks in advance!

[image: Wiring of the RPI 1]

[image: Wiring of the RPI 2]

[image: Wiring of the Amplifier 1]

[image: Wiring of the Amplifier 2]

[image: Wiring of the Speaker]

Comment: Try to run the sound test program as root, with "sudo". It only works that way for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be the SD PIN. I would try to run the speaker test:

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-max98357-i2s-class-d-mono-amp/raspberry-pi-test#simple-white-noise-speaker-test-6-1

while adjusting the voltage according to the given parameters:

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-max98357-i2s-class-d-mono-amp/pinouts#sd-slash-mode-2-15

to see if the speaker produces any sound. Also remember to ensure that the Pi volume control is set to a high enough level.

What you also could do is checking the voltage on the audio output with a voltmeter or with an oscilloscope if you have either of these.

If you don't have either turn up to max volume, run the white noise test and check if the amplifier gets hot. If it gets hot you know that there is an amplified audio signal but the speaker needs to much power to produce sound.

Furthermore you could use different applications as the audio signal source.